# I can't get the content of the web site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the contents of a website, using the library called BeautifulSoup using this code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.cora.fr"
request_page = urlopen(url)
page_html = request_page.read()
request_page.close()
html_soup = BeautifulSoup (page_html,'html.parser')
print(html_soup.prettify())
```

and i get this OutPut:

```
<html style="height:100%">
 <head>
  <meta content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" name="ROBOTS"/>
  <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"/>
  <meta content="initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
  <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <script async="" src="/aginnied-Russiuerall-is-in-Now-I-and-haue-of-per">
  </script>
 </head>
 <body style="margin:0px;height:100%">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" id="main-iframe" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWUDNSAI=31&amp;xinfo=14-57686117-0%20NNNY%20RT%281647685973667%2052%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%20-1%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B12%2814%2c0%2c0%29%20U18&amp;incident_id=578000600070663752-301165151237836558&amp;edet=12&amp;cinfo=0e000000ee8c&amp;rpinfo=0&amp;cts=6o3aY0%2bK9yRMZVnfRogZQ5mdlFz%2f4pTp9kkaulxxrjzj29yFMZc4CDDz3DEQhaUm&amp;mth=GET" width="100%">
   Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 578000600070663752-301165151237836558
  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

The Body shows a different informations instead of the actual content of the page, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The html content clearly states that `Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident`. Incapsula allows sites to block based on location.

It throws a captcha when I try to open the website on Chrome from a different country. Try using headers like in the following piece of code and try again:

```
req = urllib2.Request("https://www.cora.fr", None, {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

Or you can use a proxy in your code

Comment: I tried to add the headers and it still gives me an error

Comment: Perhaps the Incident is throwing an error since the website is French